# Inserting and deleting into a linked list error

Tags: java, class, linked-list

Writing the LinkedList class manually. Been trying to figure this out for a couple days. I need to be able to insert and delete Nodes from the list. Insertion and deletion seem to work fine until there are four or more Nodes in the list. After there are a few Nodes linked, values start to be inserted at the end of the list then mess up all insertions from there. For deletions, delete will sometimes 'delete' the first Node, making the second Node the new head. I can't see where the mistake is. I have main that implements the insert/delete methods. Below the code is sample output, but here is the code I have:

```
class SortedLinkedList {
private int size;
private Node head;

public SortedLinkedList() {
    size = 0;
    head = null;
} //constructor

public Node appropriatePosition(int k) {
    Node curr = head;

    if(head == null)
        return head;
    else if(curr.data >= k)
        return null;
    else if(curr.next == null)
        return curr;
    else if(curr.next.data > k)
        return curr;
    while(curr.next != null) { //null? write new if
        curr = curr.next; 
        }
    return curr;
}

public void insert(int k) {
    Node appPos = appropriatePosition(k);
    Node insNode = new Node(k);

    if(appPos == null && head != null) {
        insNode.next = head;
        head = insNode;
    }    
    else if(appPos == null && head == null)
        head = insNode;
    else {
        insNode.next = appPos.next;
        appPos.next = insNode;
    }
    size++;
}

public Node find(int p) {
    if(head == null)
        return null;
    if(head.data == p)
        return head;

    Node curr = head;
    Node prev = null;
    while(curr.data != p) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.next;
        if(curr == null)
            return null;
        else if(curr.data > p) {
            System.out.println("Value not found");
            return curr;
        }
        else if(curr == null)
            return null;
    }
    return prev;        
}

public void delete(int q) {
    Node findVal = find(q);
    if(head == null)
        System.out.println("Cannot delete: SortedLinkedList is empty");
    else if(findVal.data == head.data)
        head = head.next;
    else if(head.next == null)
        System.out.println("Cannot find value");
    else if(findVal == null)
            System.out.println("Cannot delete: SortedLinkedList is empty");
    else if(findVal.data > q)
        System.out.println("Value not found");
    else  {
        findVal.next = findVal.next.next;
        size--;
    }    
}

class Node {
public Node next = null;
public int data;   

public Node(int k){
    data = k;
}
public Node(Node s) {
    data = s.data;
    next = s;
}        
}
```

Sample output for insert:

Insert
Enter value: 2 Print: 
2 
Insert
Enter value: 5 Print:
2 5 
Insert
Enter value: 5 Print:
2 5 5 
Insert
Enter value: 7 Print:
2 5 5 7 
Insert
Enter value: -9 Print:
-9 2 5 5 7 
Insert
Enter value: -3 Print:
-9 -3 2 5 5 7 
Insert
Enter value: 6 Print:
-9 -3 2 5 5 7 6 
Insert
Enter value: 4 Print:
-9 -3 2 5 5 7 6 4 
Insert
Enter value: 6
-9 -3 2 5 5 7 6 4 6

Sample output for delete:

Delete
Enter value: 7 Print:
-9 -3 2 5 5 6 4 6 
Delete
Enter value: 2 Print:
-9 -3 5 5 6 4 6 
Delete
Enter value: -3 Print:
-3 5 5 6 4 6 
Delete
Enter value: -3 Print:
5 5 6 4 6

Comment: A couple of suggestions: first, name your parameters and variables with more meaningful names. Second, you have a lot of repetition in your code. Try to get rid of that. Third, please provide a complete and easy-to-read example of incorrect behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. The parameters are just simple int inputs -- though I can name them more meaningfully. The output is complete, user just enters int to insert/delete, int is used in code, then new LinkedList is printed. I have so much repetition only because I was trying to figure out the problem here by directly addressing every case. Does this help at all? Thanks for looking

Comment: What would really help is an example of that incorrect behaviour you mention. From what i see, your list isn't exactly sorted since in the end you insert 4 and it appears as the last value after 6. Is it the issue you want to fix?

Comment: That's exactly the problem for inserts. I've no idea why it's inserting at the end like of the list like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your delete was checking the wrong thing. This delete is simpler and does the trick

```
public void deleteNew(int p) {
        Node curr = head;
        Node prev = null;
        while (curr != null) {
            if (curr.data == p) {
                prev.next = curr.next;
                size--;
                break;
            }
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
```

I will work on the insert next.

```
public void insertNew(int k){
    Node prev = null, curr = head;

    Node insert = null;
    if (head == null){
        head = new Node(k);
        size++;
    }
    else{
        while (curr != null) {
            if (curr.data > k) {
                insert = new Node(k);
                insert.next = curr;
                if (prev != null)
                    prev.next = insert;
                size++;
                if (insert.data < head.data)
                    head = insert;
                break;
            }
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Saving major omissions these should be simpler and doing what you need them to do. Tried with

```
SortedLinkedList l = new SortedLinkedList();
        l.insertNew(5);
        l.insertNew(4);
        l.insertNew(3);
        l.insertNew(2);
        l.insertNew(1);
        l.insertNew(0);
        l.deleteNew(5);
        l.deleteNew(1);
        l.insertNew(1);
```